# "Squeezing" a game object based on distance to another game object

Tags: c#, unity

I am trying to "squeeze" a gameObject. When distance starts to be 6.98, execute this code: "The smaller the distance between gameObject1 and gameObject2, the thinner and longer this gameObject is". Somehow, this code has no effect. Why?

```
public Transform gameObject1;
public Transform gameObject2;

void Update ()
{
    float distance_squeeze = Vector3.Distance(gameObject1.position, 
                                              gameObject2.position);    
    if(distance_squeeze < 6.98F)
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-distance_squeeze, distance_squeeze, 1);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Which object is this script attached to?

Comment: The object that will be "squeezed".

Comment: Does this object have a parent? If not, use transform.scale.x or something similar.

Comment: Yes, my object has a parent.

Comment: Are you aware you are first computing `distance_squeeze` as distance and then you are resetting it to magic constant of value `6.98`?

Comment: Sorry, wrong piece of code. Here is the correct one: ` void Update () 
 {
     float distance_squeeze = Vector3.Distance(gameObject1.position, gameObject2.position);    
     if(distance_squeeze < 6.98F){
         transform.localScale = new Vector3(-distance_squeeze, distance_squeeze, 1);
     }   
 }`

Comment: The question has been edited.

Comment: If your code doesn't to anything (eg. no scaling at all), then you should probably try to debug it? Is your `if` condition met at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand question correctly, you wish to reduce width(*x* scale) so that total area of object is maintained. In order to do that, when setting *x* scale you need to set *y* scale to `1/x`.
Second part is finding the *x* scale. Please note that it is *relative* to object width:

```
float original_width = 6.98f; //no magic constants, this will pay off in long run
void Update () 
{
  float distance_squeeze = Vector3.Distance(gameObject1.position, gameObject2.position);  
  //note: you probably wanted to subtract gameObject2's witdth/2 here - you probably wanted distance from edge, not center
  float scale_x = distance_squeeze / original_width; //relative
  scale_x = Mathf.Min(scale_x, 1.0f); //do no stretch, equivalent to if(<6.98f)
  transform.localScale = new Vector3(scale_x, 1.0f / scale_x, 1.0f);
}
```

*note: this assumes default scale 1.0f, for details see chat linked in comments.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30728/discussion-on-answer-by-wondra-squeezing-a-game-object-based-on-distance-to-an).

Comment: Hello again! I have a question regarding your code: How can I adjust the speed of the "squeeze"? (+1)