# Unity and arduino processing

Tags: unity, input, processing, arduino

This question relates to this link: 
https://www.freetronics.com.au/blogs/news/6537043-experimenting-with-unity-processing-and-arduino#.W2-SFs4zbIU
Does anyone have any idea how I would begin doing this? I cannot find the tutorial or code that relates to this. I have a cube on unity that changes colour and texture according to the input from a force sensing resistor. How would I get the cube to react in this way (as in the video)? Any assistance will be appreciated

In this video, a flexiforce sensor is housed in a cube. When the user presses the sensor, a cube on Unity reacts in the same manner that the real cube is squeezed; its basically a virtual version of what is happening to the cube in real life

Comment: How about this? I didn't get to the bottom but apparently Unity ha a SerialPort class to handle that https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/10/07/how-to-integrate-arduino-with-unity/

Comment: I'm unable to view the link & video in their entirety from my current net connection. To make your question easier to understand for users in similar situations, it would help to edit your question to describe what you mean by "doing this" or "react in this way" in words. This also makes your question more searchable for users with relevant expertise, or users trying to solve similar problems.

Comment: I have edited the question to add some more information to my query

Comment: So just to clarify: you have the cube/unity connection working, you just want to figure out how to change the cube's shape?

Comment: Yes, I have the cube/unity and arduino part working, I just want to know how to make the cube change shape as the force is exerted on the cube. Currently the cube changes color and texture as different levels of force is exerted on it

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/113149/how-can-i-squeeze-a-game-object-when-it-is-pressed-between-two-others)?

Comment: Something that would look similar to that, yes. So I basically have certain force conditions that relate to the cube changing color and texture. Would I have to do something similar to the box collider?

Comment: Looks like the relevant code in the answer of that other question is this `float x = transform.localScale.x - squeezeForce; transform.localScale = new Vector2 (x, 1);`. I'm not familiar with Unity, and I don't have it installed, but that's the first thing I'd test.

Comment: @JoulinRouge I converted your answer to a comment because 1) it was a link only answer, 2) it was not answering the question at hand (after some back and forth with the author) and 3) it has value for future visitors.

Comment: Hey, I hate to answer in comments, and specially with links, but the page linked in the page you linked is on the [internet wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160523030625/http://www.sundh.com:80/blog/2012/05/unity-processing-arduino). Maybe that's what you need. If it is, then by all means, write an answer to your question :D

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Thank you, this looks super useful. When i get it to work, i will post the answer

Comment: Hello, thanks for coming back and posting that. You should post it as an answer and mark it as accepted to let other users know that you've resolved your issue!

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt okay i will do that. Thanks for the help by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works well:

```
     using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;
public class arduino : MonoBehaviour
{

    public SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("\\\\.\\COM5", 9600);// Com port and the baud rate of the arduino
    Material m_Material;
    GameObject Sphere;



    void Awake()
    {
        Sphere = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
        m_Material = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
    }
    void Start()
    {
        if (!sp.IsOpen)
        {
            sp.Open(); // Open 
        }
        sp.ReadTimeout = 250; // Timeout for reading 

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (sp.IsOpen)
        { // Check to see if the serial port is open 
            try
            {

                //string portreading = sp.ReadLine(); // get the string output of the serial port 
                //float amount = int.Parse(portreading);
                string value = sp.ReadTo("EOL"); //Read the information
                float amount = float.Parse(value);


                if ((amount > 251f))
                {
                    m_Material.color = Color.red;
                    Renderer _rend = Sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>();
                    Sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = _rend.material;
                    _rend.material.mainTexture = Resources.Load("face1") as Texture;
                    Sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3( 2f, 0.03f*amount, 2f);
                    //Sphere.transform.position = new Vector3(2f, 2f , 2f);
                }
                else
                {
                    m_Material.color = Color.white;
                    Sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(2f, 10f, 8f);

                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```